# Node.JS - How to limit multi-promised requests to prevent overflow (Web scraping)

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, overflow, screen-scraping

I'm receiving `FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of memory` when I execute the script which has a high amount of requests that needs to be done.

I'm assuming that I need to lower the amount of requests made? Eg: Send 5 requests (and maybe add delay) until complete, buffer to browser, then send the next batch of 5 requests... etc.

Any help appreciated!

Here's the source:

```
var http = require('http');
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var rp = require('request-promise');
var _ = require("underscore");
var dommy = require('dommy');

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
//  ** Something like this causes overflow **
//  var appIds = _.range(451131,450131);
    var appIds = [253250, 445170, 327510, 346110, 421900, 385070]

    var document = dommy();
    var html = document.createElement('html');
    var body = document.createElement('body');
    var ul = document.createElement('ul');
    var li = document.createElement('li');

    function steamappRequestConfig(appId) {
        var options = {
            uri: 'http://steamcommunity.com/games/' + appId + '/Avatar',
            transform: function(body) {
                return cheerio.load(body);
            }
        };
        return rp(options).then(function($) {
            return {
                appId: appId,
                appDom: $,
            };
        });
    }
    var appInfoRequests = appIds.map(steamappRequestConfig);
    var listPromise = Promise.all(appInfoRequests);
    listPromise.then(function(appResults) {
            appResults.sort(function(x) {
                return x.appId;
            });

            var results = appResults.map(function(rpResult) {
                var $ = rpResult.appDom;
                var appId = rpResult.appId;

                var statusCheck = $('h2').text();
                // Check if page contains Avatars
                if (statusCheck != 'Avatars') {
                    // We are sorry nothing important here
                } else {
                    return document.createTextNode('<li><a href="http://steamcommunity.com/games/' + appId + '/Avatar">' + appId + '</a></li>');
                }
            });
            // Output
            html.appendChild(body);
            body.appendChild(ul);
            ul.appendChild(results.join('\n'));
            document.appendChild(html);
            response.write(document.outerHTML);
            // console.log(document.outerHTML);
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            // Crawling failed or Cheerio choked...
        });
}).listen(80);
```

**UPDATE #1** **:** I've tried tinkering for a while, I started receiving this error on the browser:

> ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

So instead of using a web-http-server I decided *for now* to use file system.write and append to a html file. It started off great, after a while I started getting an error displayed on the terminal which are these two (on separate PCs, same script).

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

 1847363 ms: Scavenge 704.7 (738.6) -> 704.7 (738.6) MB, 25.6 / 0 ms (+ 16.0 ms in 1 steps since last GC) [allocation failure] [incremental marking delaying mark-sweep].
 1848957 ms: Mark-sweep 704.7 (738.6) -> 703.2 (738.6) MB, 1597.4 / 0 ms (+ 155.0 ms in 250 steps since start of marking, biggest step 16.0 ms) [last resort gc].
 1850473 ms: Mark-sweep 703.2 (738.6) -> 703.2 (738.6) MB, 1526.1 / 0 ms [last resort gc].


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 39E85C51 <JS Object>
    1: ontext [C:\njs\node_modules\domhandler\index.js:~102] [pc=49426425] (this=1534D645 <a DomHandler with map 170773ED>,data=1534D631 <String[4]: Home>)
    2: _parse [C:\njs\node_modules\htmlparser2\lib\Tokenizer.js:~635][pc=49412CAA] (this=1534D6A9 <a Tokenizer with map 17077839>)
    3: parseDOM [C:\njs\node_modules\htmlparser2\lib\index.js:~39] [pc=49443D56] (thi...

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of memory
```

and this:

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

 2195352 ms: Scavenge 1397.9 (1457.9) -> 1397.9 (1457.9) MB, 0.4 / 0 ms (+ 4.0 ms in 1 steps since last GC) [allocation failure] [incremental marking delaying mark-sweep].
 2196159 ms: Mark-sweep 1397.9 (1457.9) -> 1391.7 (1457.9) MB, 807.0 / 0 ms (+ 6.0 ms in 3 steps since start of marking, biggest step 4.0 ms) [last resort gc].
 2197192 ms: Mark-sweep 1391.7 (1457.9) -> 1391.7 (1457.9) MB, 1033.0 / 0 ms [last resort gc].


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 000000E4D0FE3AD1 <JS Object>
    2: _parse [F:\nodejs\njs\node_modules\htmlparser2\lib\Tokenizer.js:~635] [pc=000000821C37FA11] (this=0000011BB742F669 <a Tokenizer with map 00000071B3686C09>)
    3: write [F:\nodejs\njs\node_modules\htmlparser2\lib\Tokenizer.js:632] [pc=000000821C37BBE6] (this=0000011BB742F669 <a Tokenizer with map 00000071B3686C09>,chunk=000001EEC32D0809 <Very long string[18191]>)
    4:...

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of memory
```

If there's anyone out there that can find a remedy for this I would gladly appreciate it. These were tested with the response from *clay* using concurrency with bluebird.

Answer (score 0):

If the error is too much data being prepared for the request (or the request prematurely ended or something), you'll have to investigate elsewhere.

If the error is when processing, like your node process is having trouble, you will need to run in batches. Or really, only so many concurrent Promises at once. I would suggest a Promise library, like [bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) or [q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q), to limit the number of concurrent promises.

In bluebird, the `.map` and `.filter` methods have "concurrency options" to limit exactly as you mentioned. Check out [the API docs](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html), but it would basically be:

```
var appInfoRequests = Promise.map( appIds, steamappRequestConfig, {
  concurrency: 5 //or whatever
});
appInfoRequests.then( .....
```

Also, if you didn't need all the concurrency, you could use `.each` or `.mapSeries` (or similar) to make sure they process sequentially, rather than all at once.

Comment: how do I prevent ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE on the browser? I need to be able to buffer the concurrencies to browser right, otherwise  I think requests made are without giving error but I think this time the browser gives up.

Comment: Can you try a `response.end()` after your write?

Comment: Still doesn't work, after a while gives me that error above.

Comment: It works when I console.log without http-web-server but the moment I use web server I just get that: "ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE "